# How do I change the default font size for reading the body of messages in Mail 14.0

Tags: mail.app, big-sur, font, defaults

How do I change the default font size for reading the body of messages in Mail 14.0? I know that I can use <kbd>ctrl ⌃</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd>, but I want the reading pane to default the body of the message to a larger font without lowering the default resolution.

This is related to a previous question but the suggested methods no longer work.

Comment: using com.apple.mail MinimumHTMLFontSize no longer works --- such a simple function that otherwise omnipotent APPLE did not care to provide? Driving me carzy...

Comment: There used to be /Applications/Mail.app/Contents/Resources/message.css which could be changed for html messages.  In BS, this is no longer there and, even if it were, we could not change it (r-o system volume...).  There must be a .css somewhere controlling this.

Comment: @Gilby Thanks and fully agree with your observation! Hope someone from APPLE DEV sees this.

Answer (score 1):

Mail > Preferences > Fonts & Colors provides selectors for font style, size, usage (list, text body), and color.

Here's the Fonts & Colors preference pane:

[image]

To change the text font, style, and size, push the "Select" button that appears at the right end of the line "Message font." Doing so brings up the regular macOS font selector dialog:

[image]

Make your selections, and in a moment or two Mail.app will update its display.

Comment: thanks but unfortunately this does not change the font size in the body of messages

Comment: @user39008 I believe it does. The entry "Message font" has a button labeled "Select" at the right. Push the button. This brings up the regular macOS font select box, where the user can choose the font, style, and size. This changes the displayed font, style, and size. I'll expand the answer.

Comment: Thanks again for the effort!  Unfortunately it doesn't even when set at 288. See the earlier post here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/70727/how-do-i-change-the-default-font-size-for-reading-in-mail-6-0

Comment: @user39008 I've no idea; the cited thread indicates that if the email is in HTML, changing this preference may be ineffective. On my machine (macOS 11.2.2), however, changing this preference changes the displayed text characteristics within all emails in mailboxes in Mail.app.

Comment: Yes I believe your approach is working for plain text mails but not those in HTML coded emails.  These are not limited by commercial emails - many work emails are in this format so that pictures can be included, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I am also frustrated by this ongoing bug within Apple Mail. Perhaps this old tip of using a local style sheet would be the solution
http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20040219094626558

> ```
> <key>WebKitUserStyleSheetEnabledPreferenceKey</key>
> <true/>
> <key>WebKitUserStyleSheetLocationPreferenceKey</key>
> <string>~/benlocal.css</string>
> ```

Comment: Pls include the actions suggested in the link you have provided with as much detail as possible so that your answer keeps its informative value even if the link goes bad.

Comment: It would be fascinating if this fix from 2004 still worked.